# SCCM Keyword Search from device collection

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, sccm

is it possible to scan the device collection to search for a particular keyword.
Say a keyword like "crack", Can SCCM functionalities do a scan of all file and folder in the host/device collection to get this list. SCCM version is 1806.
Or does this need script to collect ?Generally `dir/s/tc`commmand prompt script can get file.But it is difficult when scanning 1500+ devices as reporting gets messed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Software Inventory function from Client Settings. Select "Inventory these file types" and from there you can enter filenames with wildcards. Check here for a full description:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/core/clients/manage/inventory/configure-software-inventory

Comment: Thank for the help.  I tried to do as you suggested but there was no scan results for filenames. Am i missing anything?

Comment: You cannot do something like scan for those results. You can either connect directly to the DB and do sql on results or you can create a new collection and use a query to fill it. For that you could use wql like this: "select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client from SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile on SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId where SMS_G_System_SoftwareFile.FileName like "%crack%""

Comment: Did you use *crack* as the filename to search for? Also have you waited long enough for the clients to get the updated policy and perform a Software Scan cycle? You can force them to do it using something like Recast Right Click Tools. The best report to use Is Software Files -> Computers with a specific file and use %crack% as the search term..